# Java Sockets - A Client that reads the data the server gets

Tags: java, sockets, client

I am working on a java socket program and have difulcites with the client part. The server get's what all the clients write, but the client only gets what it writes. Could someone provide me with an example of a client part of a program that gets what all the clients write? Thanks!

Comment: Please read [All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).

Comment: You would have to have the server read the message from one client, and then write that out to each client.  Or you can look into Java Message Service.

Comment: Do you mean like the sockets demo which comes with the JDK? Or the socket tutorials you can search for? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an "echo server" example

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer
{
public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException
{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    DataInputStream serverInput = null;
    PrintStream serverOutput = null;
    String line = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;

    // create server socket
    try
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2012);
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        serverInput = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        serverOutput = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch(IOException e){System.out.println(e);}


    // receive data and send it back to the client
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            line = serverInput.readLine();
            if(line.equals("exit"))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if(!line.equals(null) && !line.equals("exit"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Received " +line);
                    line = line+" MODIFIED";
                    serverOutput.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){System.out.println("SERVER SIDE: Unable send/receive data");}

    try
    {
        serverInput.close();
        serverOutput.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){System.out.println(e);}
}
}
```

Here is the client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPClient
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{

    Socket echoSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        echoSocket = new Socket("localhost", 2012);
        out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O");
        System.exit(1);
    }

BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String userInput;

while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println(userInput);
    System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
    if(userInput.equals("exit"))
    break;
}

out.close();
in.close();
stdIn.close();
echoSocket.close();
}
}
```

Comment: That looks a little like oracle's example

Comment: @user1832583 It probably is.  I haven't looked at that code in ages. It's been a file on my machine forever. Although I may have tweaked it a bit

Comment: Ok, looks good! I am going to test the datainputstream part, the rest I have!